# Read openstreetmap PBF file with PHP?

Tags: php, openstreetmap, mbtiles, openmaptiles, osm.pbf

I downloaded a `mbtiles` file from this location:
https://openmaptiles.com/downloads/europe/netherlands/

I can serve this file in `PHP` with this library :  https://github.com/klokantech/tileserver-php

This returns a compressed `PBF`, which `Mapbox GL JS` can use, but I'm not able in PHP to decode this data to get information out of it.

Has anybody ever extracted data from `PBF` using `PHP` ?

Comment: I can only give you a suggestion: there's a JavaScript library available for reading and writing this format. Have a look here: https://github.com/mapbox/pbf

Answer (score 0):

I know that this thread is a little bit old right now, but I will answer this anyway in case someone bumps into this issue.

You can use package named osm-pbf, for reading PBF files using PHP. As far as I know, it is currently the only option if you want to use PHP.

Link to package: https://github.com/franksierra/osm-pbf

Installation is fairly easy, you can just use composer.

The library itself is pretty slow, it takes around 8 minutes to read 300MB PBF file, but for smaller files it works like a charm.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30769066)